# D3.js v4, not able to see text

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am following the example [here](https://www.dashingd3js.com/svg-text-element) very closely, unfortunately I am not sure why in my version text is not showing.

I am making a time conversion on a linear scale, it works for the rects but not the text.

Here is the jsfiddle link:

https://jsfiddle.net/e1upd3kn/

JS Code:

```
/*jshint esversion: 6 */

const eventHeight = 10;
const padding = 20;
let eventYPos = 500;
let textYPos = 500;
var parseTime = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

let svgContainer = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", 1000)
    .attr("height", 500)
    .style("border", "1px dotted silver");

var mindate = new Date(1987, 3, 30),
    maxdate = new Date(2016, 9, 16);

let events = [
    {
        "start":  "1-May-95",
        "end": "1-May-14",
        "eventName": "TEST1234",
        "color": "red"
    },
    {
        "start": "1-May-01",
        "end": "1-May-04",
        "eventName": "4444",
        "color": "blue"
    },
];

var xScale = d3.scaleTime().domain([mindate, maxdate]).range([0, 1000]);
var axis = d3.axisTop().scale(xScale);
var xAxisGroup = svgContainer.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + (50 - padding) + ")")
    .call(axis);

events.forEach(function (d) {
    d.start = parseTime(d.start);
    d.end = parseTime(d.end);  
});

let rects = svgContainer
    .selectAll("rect")
    .data(events)
    .enter()
    .append("rect");
let rectsAttributes = rects
    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.start);})
    .attr("y", function (d) { eventYPos -= 10; return eventYPos; })
    .attr("width", function (d) { return xScale(d.end) - xScale(d.start); })
    .attr("height", function (d) { return eventHeight; })
    .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color; });


let texts = svgContainer
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(events)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
let textLabels = texts
    .attr("x", function (d) { return xScale(d.start);})
    .attr("y", function (d) { textYPos -= 10; return textYPos; })
    .text(function (d) { return d.eventName; })
    .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
    .attr("font-size", "20px")
    .attr("fill", "black");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do this:

```
let texts = svgContainer
    .selectAll("text")
    .data(events)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

You're binding your data to a selection that is not empty, because when this piece of code runs you already have some `text` elements in the SVG (from your x axis).

In an "enter" selection, it's important to make sure that your selection doesn't match any existing element.

That being said, it should be something like this:

```
let texts = svgContainer
    .selectAll(".text")//or anything that doesn't exist
    .data(events)
    .enter()
    .append("text");
```

Here is your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ek26rwnq/